# Unity parameter with Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

My application use Unity to inject dependency, the problem is that one of the parameter have parameter.

The class definition :

```
public ValidationEngine(params IRuleProvider[] providers)
```

I want to pass an instance of IRuleProvider as this but with unity :

```
var validationEngine = new ValidationEngine(providers: new RuleProvider(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Rules/Rates/upload/rules.xml")))
```

I have tried the code below :

```
 container.RegisterType<IValidationEngine, ValidationEngine>(ValidationConstants.RatesDownloadValidator,
                                    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ValidationEngine), new ResolvedArrayParameter<IRuleProvider>(new ResolvedParameter<RuleProvider>())));
```

But i can't add a parameter that will be use when unity instanciate the RuleProvider class.

Do i need to make my own custom ResolvedParameter -or- there is a way to pass arguments to a constructor argument ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a solution. One important point is that Unity will only resolve arrays on named registrations, so I provide the name "rulesprovider" when registering the IRuleProvider on the container:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IRuleProvider, RuleProvider>(
            "rulesprovider",
            new InjectionConstructor(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Rules/Rates/upload/rules.xml")));

container.RegisterType<IValidationEngine, ValidationEngine>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter<IRuleProvider[]>()));

var validationEngine = container.Resolve<IValidationEngine>();
```